# How to see all matches in Google Contacts?

Tags: google, google-contacts

Does anybody know how to make Google Contacts show all matching contacts and not only 5 suggestions?

I.e. If in Google Contacts I type the word “Mark”, it only shows me 5 options/suggestions of contacts with the name Mark, but I have 20 friends with that name.

How can I see all matches?

Answer (score 3):

Simply press the search button while NOT selecting any suggestion. It's the blue one with the white magnifying glass.